# GeForce GT 710 - new install w. static or mist like interference?

Tags: drivers, graphics-card

Asus GeForce GT 710 2GB DDR3
Asus P8H77-V
Windows 10 64 bit (16gb RAM) - latest system drivers and updates

I am having issues with my brand new out the box (sealed) Asus GeForce GT 710.

I know it is an old MB and new (old) graphics card but the graphics card is new out on a sealed box and on the computer this is in I do not need "game level" graphics as the machine is used just for apps like MS Office and web browsing and emails. Due to Covid 19 my children are being home schooled and need this computer to connect to their school for online lessons but due to the issues with the graphics card the computer can not be used as I do not wish to risk damaging it. For their needs this computer is more than perfect.

Using the attached VGA LCD monitor all over anything with black backgrounds there is red mist like interference and on white backgrounds there is a light blue mist liked interference on everything. The same mist is also present on backgrounds of other colours but the colour of the mist varies depending on the colour background.

As soon as you boot the machine and the ASUS logo appears with the small rotating (cursor?) icon the back ground is deeply misted red (it is normally black) and coming from the rotating icon straming out towards the right and moving black horizontal lines.

Interestingly the photo that win 10 displays just before the login screen is clean vivid and has no interference but as soon as you tap a key to access the login box the interference is back.

It does seem to get worse the longer the machine is running.

When I boot the machine and the black bootup page is shown as well as the red mist down towards the bottom there is moving dark horizontal lines.

None of this was happening with my previous Asus graphics card and is has only started since installing the new GT 710.

Here is what I have tried so far..

I installed the card to my PCle 3.0x16_1 slot (at x16 mode) as this is the one my MB manufacturer (also ASUS) recommends for single graphics so I have tried moving to a couple of the others but I still get the same issue and I loath to mess around too much as I do not want to risk damaging the MB.

I tried 5 different VGA Cables (one brand new) and connecting two other different monitors plus uninstalling the GT 710 drivers, cold reboot and reinstalling the drivers but all produced the same mist like interference.

I went to the ASUS downloads section and searched for the latest drivers for my card and downloaded and installed 451.48-desktop-win1064bit-international-dch-whql.exe. As I do not want to play games on my machine and only selected to install the graphics driver and none of the other software but I still have the same issues.

Can you kindly help?

Comment: In the BIOS, check for a Legacy PCI mode setting. Swap that over to what it is now, to the opposite. You might need to put your old GPU back in to get into the BIOS. I have the exact same issue with a GTS 750. I have to put my 450 back in, toggle the Legacy PCI mode and then put my 750 back in.

Comment: Dont need the graphics card on that H77 MOBO as it has a superior iGPU. Then install Win8 . It supports dual 1080 displays.

Comment: Test different resolution in basic graphics mode and which one fits best and once found make the changes permanent and reboot